# Get view result depending on pager url

Tags: 7, views

In drupal 7 ,this returns the results of the view first page, if using a pager:
Is there a way to get the results depending on the page? (depending on url argument maybe?)

```
$result = views_get_view_result('viewname', 'displayname');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test the code. But you can use this code.

```
$page = 1;
$view = views_get_view('payment_schedule_students');
$view->set_display('payment_schedule_students_select');
$view->set_current_page($page);
$view->execute();$view->result;
```

Where you can set the `$page` variable from the url.